# django cycle as loop break tool

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible to use cycle template tag to break some loop, then add some tag and continue with loop on 5th cycle? I have some list with number of images and it can be 100 or more images in the list but after every 5th image I need to close div tag which hold them and to open new one. Does this can be done with cycle and how? If not what is the better way for this?

```
 <div class="holder">
      img1 img2 img3 img4 img5
 </div>
 <div class="holder">
      img6 img7 img8 img9 img10
 </div>
 ....
 ....
```

Comment: ... Why not just use it to close the div?

Comment: yes I want to use it to close div and open new one but how?

Comment: ... With "</div><div>".

Comment: great Ignacio :) ` {% cycle what? %}  `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
    {% if forloop.first %}<div class="holder">{% elif forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"5" %}</div><div class="holder">{% endif %}
           <img>
        {% if forloop.last}</div>{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks @professorDante works as expected even without cycle tag